# How to read barcode using Webcam in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a project where I'm trying to  open a  webcam in django as code reader. I followed this tutorial: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xz9MvyKGYio&list=WL&index=24&t=12s" where it's istruction how to open camera in django.
I would like the webcam read barcode and redirect this code to another function. But i don't know how to break webcam and redirect when code is exist.
So it's my views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
import cv2
import threading
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse, HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators import gzip
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import time
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'webcam/home.html')

# Create your views here.
@gzip.gzip_page
def home(request):
    #https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xz9MvyKGYio&list=WL&index=23&t=12s
    try:
        cam = VideoCamera()
        return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(cam), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
    except:
        pass
    return render(request, 'app1.html')

def helloView(request, code):
    http = f"Hello {code}"
    return HttpResponse(http)

#to capture video class
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame ) = self.video.read()
        threading.Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()
    def get_frame(self):
        image = self.frame
        _, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        ################################
        # capture code /simple example / 
        n_1 = '9788366384088'
        for code in decode(image):
            n = str(code.data.decode('utf-8'))
            if n_1 == n:
                print(n)
                time.sleep(5)
                # how to redirect to helloView?
        ###########################
        return jpeg.tobytes()

    def update(self):
        while True:
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.video.read()

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
```

In VideoCamera.get_frame I added simple example where I try capture n_1 code   but I can't redirect that code to helloView. To Cut a Long Story Short:
**I open the browser where is live webcam -> I scan the ean code -> If ean code is correct redirect to helloView()**
Is it possible to do it ? And where I should capture ean code ?

Answer (score 1):

Python will be on the server you can't run it from the client side. You will need to scanner the barcode using JavaScript and pass it to python.

If you don't want the page to refresh you can us Ajax to get the data back. Depending on your version of Django just take note that from Django 3.1 > request.ajax() has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a python code in the frontend. You will need to use Javascript to load the camera and transfer the picture to the backend. Then you can use openCV to extract the code.

Read about webrtc (https://webrtc.org/) to access camera in the frontend.